# Applying animation to only entering activity android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-animation

I want to apply activity change transition to only entering activity.Suppose i am pushing A-> B then i want A activity remains still and B comes from Bottom to Top.

I applied following code but not working

```
 startActivityForResult(intent, SET_FILTER_REQUEST);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.translate_in_anim, R.anim.stay_still_anim);
```

i m using following xml file for animation

stay_still_anim.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

and

translate_in_anim.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:fillAfter="true">
  <translate android:fromYDelta="100"
         android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Comment: overridePendingTransition(R.anim.translate_in_anim, 0);

Comment: not working i already tried this

Comment: please read the doc. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int). Where first argument is enter animation and second is exit animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix this by using

```
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

abc_slide_in_bottom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
           android:fromYDelta="50%p" android:toYDelta="0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

just keep R.anim.out empty:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</set>
```

then:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.translate_in_anim, R.anim.out);
```

that will finish activity by default animation.

Answer (score 3):

So Basically if you correct you animation xml files , it will work perfectly for you . 
First thing what you have to note is , provide animation duration time same for both Xml. and also correct your ***fromYDelta*** value from **100** to **100%** like shown below. you could copy this and paste it to your code.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fillAfter="true">
     <translate android:fromYDelta="100%"
     android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>

<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```